# kernel multitouch events injection / example / source where can I find?

Tags: drivers, kernel, multi-touch

I'm developing a kernel driver for a multitouch digitizer. How can I find an example of how should the event be injected to the OS subsystem?

Is there any open source driver out there that could serve as a start point?

Is there any place where I can find official documentation about this?

Any help regarding to this would be great.

Thanks in advance,

With my best regards,

Nuno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read [input documentation](http://kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/) for the Linux kernel.

Perhaps more specifically the [Multi-touch Protocol](http://kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/multi-touch-protocol.txt).

You can also get help at the [Linux Kernel Mailing List](http://lkml.org/) (LKML).